# Cyrillic UTF8 to ASCII with XQuery

Tags: unicode, ascii, xquery, non-ascii-characters, cyrillic

I need to generate String ID's from Cyrillic data using only ASCII characters. I'm using XQuery to grab the data from XML files. This is the point where I can convert any Cyrillic characters into ASCII characters.

I've tried using `normalize-unicode($string, FORM)` with `FORM` as each of the four [Normalization Forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms), but I don't think it has any mappings from Cyrillic to English, at least it doesn't change the `$string` input.

For example, I want:

```
normalize-unicode("Идејата", 'NFKD')
```

To produce something along the lines of:

```
"NAejaTa"
```

Are there any functions in XQuery that can do this sort of thing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Search for *transliteration* or *romanization*. You should find some tools avaliable (but most would transliterate `И` into `I` and `д` into `d`, though - I don't know if that's what you want).

Comment: Normalization is not the way to go, this is meant for characters with some addition (like ä, é or ê). However, a Cyrillic д is simply a different character than d. As mapping from Cyril to latin is a simply mapping, you could simply write your own function, replacing the characters.

Comment: @helderdarocha Isn't И to I and д to d the perfectly correct transliteration? I think it should be, at least that's what I remember from my Russian lessons (but that was quite some time ago and I don't remember much, so...)

Comment: That's right @dirkk. I mentioned that *most* would transliterate that way because it's the standard way to do it. It depends on the destination language, though, since it represents sounds. ч for example becomes "ch" in English, but "tch" in Portuguese transliteration. But there is also a popular form which is based on what the letters look like and is commonly used in internet texts, chats, twitter, etc. For example, using "4" to mean "ч" (very common), and "w" to mean "ш" (less common), as in "o4enj xorowo" (очень хорошо) which would normally be transliterated (English) as "ochen' horosho".

Comment: If you really want visual rather than semantic similarity, look for a  [Volapuk encoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volapuk_encoding). Not much use for it these days though, `Ideјata` would generally be considered a much more useful transliteration of the word.

Comment: If all you want to do is generate unique IDs using the text (as the question suggests), it may be simplest to specify your own 1:1 transliteration with `translate()`.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm going to have to write my own translation function. Thanks a bunch everyone, I've learnt some useful stuff here!